# python oracle if else issues for rows fetch

Tags: python, if-statement, cx-oracle

my requirements is following. Find a count(*) for a table and if not exists, create one.following is the sample code to show the issue. in both cases the else condition is coming. not sure how I achieve this, any help is appreciated.

```
import cx_Oracle
import os
import datetime

ts = datetime.datetime.now()
con = cx_Oracle.connect('xxxx/xxxx@xxxxx:1521/xxxxx')
print con.version
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select count(*) from AAA.AAA_TEST')
rows = cur.fetchall();
print rows
print len(rows)
if (rows ==1):
  print 'there is a row'
else:
  print 'there is no row'


#result 1 where the row exists
11.2.0.4.0
[(1,)]
1
there is no row

Process finished with exit code 0

#result 2 where the row do not exists
11.2.0.4.0
[(0,)]
1
there is no row

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT COUNT(*)` always returns a row — either with 0 if there are no object in the table or with the number of objects. So there is always 1 row and you should test the count, not the number of rows. So use `if (rows[0][0] >= 1):`

`rows[0]` returns the first row, `rows[0][0]` gives the first column of the first row; for your `SELECT COUNT(*)` the first column is the count, so you test if the count is 0 of if it's >= 1.

Comment: Sorry that does not help, if you see in the code, i already used that and in both cases it showed 1.

Comment: sorry, wait a min please, I will update you. it seems to work this way. Let me do couple of tests. Thanks in advance.